# Is there no logical way to return item option fields from PayPal in a standard cart checkout?

Tags: php, curl, paypal

In addition to our regular processing, we have integrated the option for customers of our site to check out with their shopping cart through PayPal, using a combination of PayPal IPN & PDT to record the transaction. We've had the code completed for almost a year, and it works reliably and as expected. However, we have been extremely hesitant to implement it until recently for this reason: **We cannot determine any reasonable way to return or retrieve *item option values* post-checkout from PayPal.**

We *have* to have these item options. For example, we have a slightly complicated system that when a user adds an item, let's say a t-shirt, there are two item option IDs indicating the color and size of the t-shirt. These are stripped out from PayPal before being returned to us, meaning we only get the general item, and not specifically what the customer ordered.

Here is our dilemma:

1) [While the documentation clearly states that you can send PayPal on0_ and os0_](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/pdn/howto_checkout-outside) variables with the item option information, we cannot determine any way to have it return these back to you. Below is a stripped down sample of the item return values.

This is sent to PayPal:

```
<input type="hidden" name="item_number_1"   value="10272">        
<input type="hidden" name="amount_1"        value="19.95">
<input type="hidden" name="shipping_1"  value="3.55">
<input type="hidden" name="quantity_1"  value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="on0_1"   value="15001">           
<input type="hidden" name="on1_1"   value="14000">
```

This is returned from PayPal (stripped to only have relevant item info):

```
Post Vars: Array
(
   [item_number1] => 10272
   [num_cart_items] => 1
   [mc_handling1] => 3.55
   [mc_shipping1] => 3.55
   [item_name1] => [Complete Item Description...]
   [mc_gross_1] => 25.00
   [transaction_subject] => Shopping Cart[complete item description]
   [payment_gross] => 25.00
   [ipn_track_id] => 4f3054cc843ba
)
```

2) From what I understand, there IS a custom field. A single custom field. However, our customers can have 10 or more items in their shopping carts, and most items would have one to three item options. So we'd have to create a parseable pseudo-array of item IDs, options and numbers as a string of text to place in the custom field to simply have our item's options returned to us. This hacky workaround appears to be  the "Best chance" option we've got, however it is also not feasible because there is a 256 character limit, so we could not rely on the information returned.

3) So, if I'm correct, we cannot receive or retrieve returns of *Item Option* variables. But, if PayPal simply returned customers to our website after checking out, then we could still retrieve the session variables, which DO contain full shopping cart information. So when PayPal redirects users, we CAN get information. Except when users check out, they are NOT automatically redirected to PayPal, and instead the choice to redirect is *optional* and in a small, easy to miss link post-checkout -- meaning not technically reliable by any means.

Ultimately, we went ahead and began accepting PayPal, having to manually go retrieve item options for every customer on PayPal.com, and simply had code in the redirect page to correctly populate orders from users that DID choose to redirect, populating which orders we reasonably could. We had about a hundred orders, and few of them actually redirected back to our site.

4) We tried passing custom variables in hidden input fields, however, in line with PayPal's documentation, these seem to be stripped out before being returned.

5) It is not a realistic or feasible for us to create a custom database record for every user that clicks "PayPal" to store the information for retrieval if or when the IPN comes back. This is not a solution.

**UPDATE:** 
6) As per a user suggestion, we tried a call to PayPal's [GetTransactionDetails()](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_NVP/) through the rather unhelpful use of some [documentation here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/gs_transaction/). This did not return item options, instead it returns an array similar to what's returned in the PDT in this format:

```
[40] => L_NUMBER0=10100
```

We may have to shut the PayPal option off again if we cannot find an acceptable fix to this problem. We simply cannot determine any actual way to return item option values, yet using PayPal's cart system, we absolutely have to let the user leave our site to finish checking out, and complete cart data is not returned to us, so it appears we cannot record complete customer transactions unless we want to store transaction data of every single person who clicks the "PayPal" button. Is this correct?

Is there *any* way to accomplish this that we're missing? If PayPal's cart solution is the best way to check out, why does PayPal not return the cart's *data?*

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I do.

1) Create an order identifier and store all the items that the user is buying into a table. In an ideal system you would have a SKU (stock keeping unit) for every possible combination of item you sell, e.g:

- Green tee with Alien print
- Green tee with Fish print
- Red tee with Alien print

So against the order ID you would store these SKU IDs, the quantity, any additional info, i.e. if there's a discount applied maybe.

2) Pass the invoice ID to PayPal and then you can recall it on the IPN.

3) For user's who don't go all the way through the payment process you can create a cron job to clear out unwanted data. Run it every so often against the time the order was initialised, if that order is older than a set amount of time (because PayPal can get delayed), then remove it from the table.

Comment: Thanks @Diggersworld!! We're aware of this potential option, (see #5) but our circumstances make this very technically challenging, and it would require a great deal of man-hours and changes to our system. The option is an absolute last resort, and honestly, we've determined that it's basically more feasible to simply NOT accept PayPal than it is to write this workaround.

Comment: Without knowing your "circumstances" I can't really suggest anything else. Really and truly when you use any third-party payment system it should only know what it needs to know (i.e. prices, bit of description for the customer), and your system should do the rest.

Comment: Thanks Diggersworld. That is very, absolutely true about what it needs to know. I would gladly and happily use literally ANY other method, but you also know that PayPal's checkout system forces the user to leave the retailer website to conduct the transaction off-site, then returns the cart and checkout information to the website, unlike a standard Authorize.net transaction, and that particular IPN/PDT system provides no alternative. If the ONLY solution is to create a copy of every single cart that presses the PayPal button, that is not a reasonable long-term way to deal with this problem.

Comment: Does your current system handle stock, and does it handle orders/transaction history?

Comment: It does handle both, yes. The problem with the solution you suggested is that it costs a lot of man-hours and coding time that, as a small business, we simply do not have, which is why we ruled it out in the question above.

Answer (score 0):

diggersworld has the "Correct"/best answer; put the cart info in a table (or other store) as a pending order so that you can retrieve it (via invoice ID) and complete it when you get the IPN if there was no return that provides PDT information.

There are many, many other ways to skin this cat, though. A few others:

- the GetTransactionDetails docs say it returns item option information; call this when you get the IPN messages to get the particular PayPal fields you do not get in the raw IPN
- use a bit of javascript to copy/jam your option selection information into your item descriptions (and then parse it back out when handling IPNs)
- switch to using Express Checkout so that the customer is always redirected (pre-payment) and you can use your session variables to create the order exactly as you do with other payment methods after you call DoEC

But as diggersworld says, in general asking your payments provider to handle (even pass through) arbitrarily-complex entities is not the best path. Visa doesn't care about yout T-shirt sizes and colors, and PayPal shouldn't either. If your fulfillment processes require that, you are not on the firmest ground.

Comment: For the record, comparing Visa's gateway and PayPal are apples and oranges. Processors only authorize the charge. PayPal's cart system in question is *not* a processing gateway; it *is* a shopping cart that leaves your site, meaning it knows you will no longer have information from that point on, and returns (some of) it to you. I never asked PayPal to handle it; they force it. PayPal does have a gateway just like Visa, but that's not this, nor what I'm asking about. Thanks for the suggestions though, Geewiz, there's some new ground in here that we haven't touched.

Comment: Agreed that PayPal is not just a gateway; the PayPal account model uses username/password (or other account-level secrets) rather than card number. And critically, PayPal does not let other companies handle their account holders' "secret" information (password, rather than card number, in PayPal's case). This is how they run dramatically lower fraud than credit cards (heh). But this is still very similar to other "hosted" gateway solutions designed to reduce merchant's card handling and PCI exposure, and is definitely is NOT a shopping cart.

Comment: lol @ security. Here's the thing: they present PayPal Shopping Cart as a shopping cart solution, and that solution, very similar to a system like 2Checkout.com, should return certain pieces of data. But it does not. The question is ultimately not about the theoretical differences in card processing solutions, it is *IF* there is any way to retrieve this data other than the methods listed above.